# Exception thrown: 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.DataSourceException'

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2019

I'm developing an application in visual studio using c# and Crystal report. I'm getting some problem to connect db access to my app. I found out some example about that , but no work for me.
Just I need to connect a db and print it on viewer, but I found example with oledbConnect + OleDbDataAdapter. I have to pass only string connection to report.SetDataSource.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string pathReport;
       
        private const string CONNECTION_STRING = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\Xtreme.mdb";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog
            {
                InitialDirectory = @"D:\",
                Title = "Browse Text Files",

                CheckFileExists = true,
                CheckPathExists = true,

                DefaultExt = "txt",
                Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*",
                FilterIndex = 2,
                RestoreDirectory = true,

                ReadOnlyChecked = true,
                ShowReadOnly = true
            };

            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                pathReport = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                  
            }
        }
 
       
        private void btnViewer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
               
                OleDbConnection oleDbConnection = new OleDbConnection(CONNECTION_STRING);
             
                ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
                 rd.Load(@pathReport);
                               
                rd.SetDataSource(oleDbConnection);
           
                crViewer.ReportSource = rd;
                crViewer.Refresh();
       
                

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error click viewer " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

     
    }
```

[load access informazion](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/613883/Failed-to-load-database-information-error-in-cryst)

[ODBC Driver](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-access-accdb-odbc-driver/)

The report connection into Visual Studio work fine.
Can anyone give me some info to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One suspect is a 32-bit vs 64-bit mismatch.
For example, if VS is 32-bit but you are deploying as a 64-bit app.

A 64-bit app must use a 64-bit ODBC DSN or a 64-bit database connectivity driver.

Comment: Yes it's true. Yesterday I found out the same solution. Thanks for your help.